# How to see time stamps in bash history?

Tags: command-line, bash, environment-variables, history, timestamp

Is there any way I can see at what time the commands were executed from the bash history? We can see the order but is there any way I can get the time also?

Bottom-Line: Execution time in the Bash history

Comment: I'm amazed how poorly documented this is both on Linux and BSD in the manpages.

Comment: Check this blog out - https://sanctum.geek.nz/arabesque/better-bash-history/ .

Comment: if you're using zsh: `history -E`

Comment: Not sure why two answers below feel the need to tell you how to open a terminal..

Comment: According to the blog referenced by @dog0 , timestampse apparently do not get saved unless the `HISTTIMEFORMAT` variable was set when commands were issued. In other words, if you didn't have it set, setting it now will not help you retrieve timestamps of previously issued commands.

Comment: @TomislavNakic-Alfirevic For me on ubuntu 22 with stock setup, I can export HISTTIMEFORMAT at any time and next history shows the correct timestamps.

Answer (score 472, accepted):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open a terminal, then run one of the commands below:

```bsh
HISTTIMEFORMAT="%d/%m/%y %T "  # for e.g. “29/02/99 23:59:59”
HISTTIMEFORMAT="%F %T "        # for e.g. “1999-02-29 23:59:59”
```

To make the change permanent for the current user run:

```bsh
echo 'HISTTIMEFORMAT="%d/%m/%y %T "' >> ~/.bashrc  # or respectively
echo 'HISTTIMEFORMAT="%F %T "' >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

To test the effects run:

```bsh
history
```

For more info see [man bash](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html) or [An A-Z Index of the Bash command line for Linux](http://ss64.com/bash/).

For commands that were run *before* `HISTTIMEFORMAT` was set, the *current* time will be saved as the timestamp. Commands run after `HISTTIMEFORMAT` was set will have the proper timestamp saved.

Comment: Note that this will [only record timestamps for **new** history items](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87740/histtimeformat-does-not-show-correct-date-and-time-for-history), after `HISTTIMEFORMAT` is set for sessions, i.e. you can't use this retrospectively. Some answers here give the impression the history command immediately shows timestamped entries

Comment: @Jamil: for people who follow ISO standards, it's "%y-%m-%d" for the date part ;)

Comment: Just a note to zsh users out there - unlike many builtins it does not mirror bash. See this instead: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/103398/datetime-stamp-when-running-history-command-in-zsh-shell

Comment: uses the time format of strftime, which unfortunately doesn't appear to have any way to display milliseconds... (at least not portably, %f is claimed to work on some systems???)

Comment: @Gauthier - actually, just use %F for ISO date ;-) http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html

Comment: `HISTTIMEFORMAT="%d/%m/%y %T " history` works

Comment: Weirdly, this _did_ appear to work for me retrospectively - I was able to see the timestamps of history items prior to my explicit setting of this environment variable. That may be because `HISTTIMEFORMAT` was set to an empty string before, or something similar?

Comment: [Quick and dirty](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/103407/72988) for **ZSH** Timestamp

Comment: It shows correct timestamps restrospectively for **current session only**. For older sessions is seems to show login time of the session, or something similar.

Answer (score 104):

Open terminal<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and run,

```
HISTTIMEFORMAT="%d/%m/%y %T "
```

then,

```
history
```

#### To make the changes permanent follow the below steps,

```
gedit ~/.bashrc
```

you need to add the below line to .bashrc file and then save it,

```
export HISTTIMEFORMAT="%d/%m/%y %T "
```

run the below command to source .bashrc file,

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

After that run `history` command.

[image]

**source**:http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-bash-history-display-date-time/

Comment: Thanks for answering , \will it be permanent change ?

Comment: Hey, I'm doing this in OS X and Windows (through MINGW), and I'm adding it into .bash_profile, what's the diff between profile and rc?

Comment: `HISTTIMEFORMAT="%d/%m/%y %T " history` works

Answer (score 25):

Yes, you can: if you set `$HISTTIMEFORMAT`, the `.bash-history` will be properly timestamped. That doesn't help with existing `.bash-history` content, but will help in the future.

Comment: can you expand it for more clarity ?

Comment: Correction to previous post: Setting HISTTIMEFORMAT enables the display of the timestamps...even existing. My favorite is:HISTTIMEFORMAT='%F %T ' as it matters not from which country you reside...everyone knows immediately what time it is. :)

Comment: I set $HISTTIMEFORMAT and I got the times for today even before the commands of this set.

Comment: @user491029 "...even existing".  This is true, but misleading.  On ubuntu 14.04, at least, it did start showing timestamps for all history entries once I had set HISTTIMEFORMAT, but it looks like the timestamps for any command run before the current session were the login timestamp of the current session.

Answer (score 17):

Changing `HISTIMEFORMAT` didn't work for me, because I'm using zsh.

If you want to make it work with zsh, you just have to type :
`history -i`

Comment: zsh: 1, bash: 0

Answer (score 3):

You 'll see changes on next login.

```
echo 'HISTTIMEFORMAT="%d/%m/%y %T "' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 3):

My version that works

```
HISTTIMEFORMAT="%F %T %z " history | grep 'your command'
```

ref. https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/07/bash-history-how-to-show-timestamp-when.html

E.g.

```
╭you@your-server:/some/path 
╰$ HISTTIMEFORMAT="%F %T %z "; history | grep 'some command'
 1947  2019-12-17 15:54:34 +0800 ./some.sh
 1948  2019-12-17 15:54:34 +0800 ./my-command
```

View full syntax for `HISTTIMEFORMAT` [here](https://www.networkworld.com/article/2923844/bash-history-remembering-what-you-did-and-when-you-did-it.html)

Answer (score 2):

To enable history timestamps for all users, create a script in /etc/profile.d :

```
echo 'HISTTIMEFORMAT="%Y%m%d %T "' >> /etc/profile.d/timestamp.sh
```

Comment: This will likely not work for users logging in via the GUI, since the default terminal will not run login shells. `/etc/bash.bashrc` would be a  better place.

Comment: Make sure permission of /etc/profile.d/timestamp.sh is '644' , so that history command shows timestamp for all users .

Answer (score 1):

I maintain a history per tty device per user, in .bash_profile, and let them grow large. Sometimes I want to find where a command was used across all those files using grep, say.
I have just spent a while getting how I want, with time stamps as strings and headers for each file plus which tty before the time so if I am grepping I will see where and when used:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS="#"; FS="\n"} {if (FNR == 1){ print "\n==>" FILENAME "<=="; tty=substr(FILENAME,15,9) }; if ((ln==0) && ($1 ~/^[0-9]+$/)){Cmd="date -r "$1""; Cmd | getline textDate; close(Cmd);baseD=substr(textDate,1,length(textDate)-5);baseS=$1}; if ($1 ~/^[0-9]+$/){printf "%s %s+%.2fH (%d)%s\n",  tty, baseD, ($1-baseS)/3600, $1, $2; if (ln==0) {ln=20} else {ln--}}} ' .bash_history_ttys003|head

==>.bash_history_ttys003<==
ttys003 Thu 28 Sep 2017 10:45:48+0.00H (1506591948)cp Qlog t
ttys003 Thu 28 Sep 2017 10:45:48+6.12H (1506613974)grep \ 755\  Qlog
ttys003 Thu 28 Sep 2017 10:45:48+6.15H (1506614092)grep \ 769\  Qlog
ttys003 Thu 28 Sep 2017 10:45:48+6.16H (1506614130)locate akd
ttys003 Thu 28 Sep 2017 10:45:48+6.17H (1506614159)less /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.akd.plist
ttys003 Thu 28 Sep 2017 10:45:48+6.17H (1506614172)mN -K PLIST
ttys003 Thu 28 Sep 2017 10:45:48+6.18H (1506614179)man -k plist
ttys003 Thu 28 Sep 2017 10:45:48+6.18H (1506614213)man swapllist
```

Can't go into all the background as life is too short (LITS) but here are my dev notes as I worked it up. This is on macOS so no special gawk but I do use date -r where it may differ for you, date -d?. Enjoy! :

```
How would I list all .bash_history* lines that grep finds together with the Unix timestamp as string?
sample data lines in history (#unix time \n command)
head .bash_history_ttys007
\#1502956374
man top
\#1502956600
top

As 2 lines looks like an awk task...
Can't print FILENAME in begin as there is no current file at that stage :( so use FNR file rec numb check...
awk 'BEGIN{RS="#"} {if (FNR == 1){ print FILENAME }; "date -r "$1"" | getline textDate; close(date);print textDate, $0}'
awk 'BEGIN{RS="#"} {if (FNR == 1){ print FILENAME }; "date -r "$1"" | getline textDate; close(date);print textDate, $0}' .bash_history_ttys00[67]|head
Works but 3 lines per item as x0a line-returns are in there. WILL HAVE OTHER PROBLEMS TOO (later)...
Progress by field sep on new lines and carve up filename for controlling terminal
awk 'BEGIN{RS="#"; FS="\n"} {if (FNR == 1){ print "\n==>" FILENAME "<=="; tty=substr(FILENAME,15,9) }; if ($1 ~/^[0-9]+$/){"date -r "$1"" | getline textDate; close(date);print  tty, substr(textDate,1,length(textDate)-1) ,"(" $1")", $2} }' .bash_history_ttys00[67]|head

$ awk 'BEGIN{RS="#"; FS="\n"} {if (FNR == 1){ print "\n==>" FILENAME "<=="; tty=substr(FILENAME,15,9) }; if ($1 ~/^[0-9]+$/){"date -r "$1"" | getline textDate; close(date -r "$1");print  tty, substr(textDate,1,length(textDate)-1) ,"(" $1")", $2} }' .bash_history_ttys002

Works OK but runs a bit slow: just do dates every once in a while? then if grep-ing will probably miss it...
awk 'BEGIN{RS="#"; FS="\n"} {if (FNR == 1){ print "\n==>" FILENAME "<=="; tty=substr(FILENAME,15,9) }; if ($1 ~/^[0-9]+$/){Cmd="date -r "$1""; Cmd | getline textDate; close(Cmd);print  tty, substr(textDate,1,length(textDate)-1) ,"(" $1")", $2} }' .bash_history_ttys002

Do occasional date convert and retain string and offset secs? this does run much faster and requires timestamps to avoid # in commands. About 5s for 20,000 commands for me.
awk 'BEGIN{RS="#"; FS="\n"} {if (FNR == 1){ print "\n==>" FILENAME "<=="; tty=substr(FILENAME,15,9) }; if ((ln==0) && ($1 ~/^[0-9]+$/)){Cmd="date -r "$1""; Cmd | getline textDate; close(Cmd);baseD=substr(textDate,1,length(textDate)-5);baseS=$1}; if ($1 ~/^[0-9]+$/){printf "%s %s+%.2fH (%d)%s\n",  tty, baseD, ($1-baseS)/3600, $1, $2; if (ln==0) {ln=20} else {ln--}}} ' .bash_history_ttys003
```

Answer (score 0):

I know, I'm answering it very late, but to do this for all the users, you can create any `.sh` file in `/etc/profile.d` and add the following line to it:

```
echo 'HISTTIMEFORMAT="%Y-%m-%d %T "' >> /etc/profile.d/existing-foo-file.sh
```

If you not logged in as `root` or superuser, you need to use the `tee` command to do this:

```
echo 'HISTTIMEFORMAT="%Y-%m-%d %T "' | sudo tee /etc/profile.d/mytimestamp.sh
```

If you want to append to any existing file, pass `-a` flag to `tee` command:

```
echo 'HISTTIMEFORMAT="%Y-%m-%d %T "' | sudo tee -a /etc/profile.d/mytimestamp.sh
```

[image]

Comment: Hello Shashank, Thanks for adding the answer but how this answer is different from others ? If your answer is completely different then we are glad to have it, but if not you can improve existing answers.

Comment: Hi, thanks for commenting. This is different from others in the following way: 
1. Some of them have mentioned about creating for all users but no one mentioned about creating/explaining any file name in `/etc/profile.d`. `timestamp.sh` looks very close to technical (so it creates confusion) so I used the name `existing-foo-file.sh` (foo-bar concept).
2. No one has mentioned about using it with non-root users. So I have given an example of using `sudo`.
3. The 3rd example improves the 2nd example of appending to an existing file.
Since linux/unix beginners can hit this issue, I elaborated.

Comment: Just a note : Make sure permission of /etc/profile.d/timestamp.sh is '644' , so that history command shows timestamp for all users . In my case permission of '/etc/profile.d/timestamp.sh' was '640' , because of which users other than owner was not seeing timeformatted history .

Comment: Thanks @sjethvani