# What do the numbers mean in output of history?

Tags: command-line, bash, history, bash-history

Output of `history` command looks like this:

```
1975  mkdir adrnln/work_dump
1976  ls
1977  code
```

1. What do the numbers on the left side mean?
2. Is it true that commands entered for example on Monday will be displayed higher than those one entered on Tuesday?
3. If above is true, why I can see some commands like `ssh` entered yesterday displayed lower than commands I entered today.

Comment: In order to know when a command was typed, you could set the `HISTTIMEFORMAT` variable. Check this out: http://askubuntu.com/questions/391082/how-to-see-time-stamps-in-bash-history

Answer (score 4):

1. History can only store amount. When it reaches 1000 entries, it can't store more. So if you have 1500 commands, it will display the most recent 1000 (500 to 1500).

   You can also use the command !N (where N is the number) to run that command again.
   This is an output of my recent history:

   ```
   336  cp monitors.tim monitors.xml
   337  cd .config/
   338  cp monitors.tim monitors.xml
   339  xrandr
   340  sudo nvidia-settings
   341  cd .config/
   342  cp monitors.xml monitors.tim
   343  gedit monitors.xml 
   344  cd .config/
   345  gedit monitors.xml
   ```

   To rerun the 337<sup>th</sup>  command, I just do `!337`. My new history:

   ```
   336  cp monitors.tim monitors.xml
   337  cd .config/
   338  cp monitors.tim monitors.xml
   339  xrandr
   340  sudo nvidia-settings
   341  cd .config/
   342  cp monitors.xml monitors.tim
   343  gedit monitors.xml 
   344  cd .config/
   345  gedit monitors.xml
   346  cd .config/
   ```
2. It should work that way.
3. History isn't designed to be perfectly in order - just remember everything. But if you would have two terminal windows open, exit the newer and then still stay in the older, the older one will then have the "history" of the newer but "before" the "history" of the current terminal.

Comment: Now it's worthy of an upvote!  ;-)  Still no clue on how to get your dual cards working though...  :-(