# Terminal command for getting information about the time and user of all the commands executed in all sessions of terminal

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions, gnome-terminal, logs

I want to know which user executed which command on terminal and when i.e. if any of the user does "rmdir abc" and removes a specific directory , i should know which command he executed and at what time.And i don't want it for a single session, this data should be available to me like we maintain logs, so that i can analyze it for any point of time.

I tried the `history` command as well and also added time to it but it does not show "Users" of the command and also it is session based ,so it's data does not get appended to `~/.bash_history` file unless the session is exited. Also `~/.bash_history` does not show time and user so it's not usefull.Can anyone help me please.I just want to see which user executed which command from the moment the system is started and at what time.

Comment: What is your end goal? Anything based on simple shell history can be easily circumvented by the user. Perhaps you should be looking at something like `pam_tty_audit.so`? See for example [How do I log every command executed by a user?](https://serverfault.com/a/336234)

Comment: thanks for replying @steeldriver. My ultimate goal is to log data about all commands executed by all users along with timestamp. And if it is possible then i even want to see non-command actions of the users as well , like if they delete a file from UI or any other source and not through command.

Answer (score 0):

You can check commands that executed by users using `sudo vim /home/USER_YOU_WANT_TO_VIEW/.bash_history`

For more you can also check AUTH logs `tail /var/log/auth.log | grep username`

try this similar question : [How to see time stamps in bash history?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/391082/how-to-see-time-stamps-in-bash-history)

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Sanjay , but like i said history commands work session wise and auth.log will contain information only till specific time period , after that it will be gone.Can you suggest anything else please.Also can you tell me how to read time stamp in ```~/.bash_history``` file

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is in all users own bash history file.
You just need to get list of .bash history files and cat them.

```
cd /home
find |grep .bash_history
```

outputs :

```
./gediz/.bash_history
```

than cat it

```
cat ./gediz/.bash_history
```

You can do it in a for loop

```
a=find ...
for i in $a
do
echo $a
cat $i
done
```

You can make a service or edit rc.local file for ubuntu startup with a while loop which backups all users .bash_history in every loop to a secure location so that even if users delete theirs you will be able to check what has been done.