# how to save to log all commands made with gnome terminal

Tags: log

Need to get logs for commands used on daily basis.
I believe there are these kind of logs
How can I locate these?

By commands I understand my input commands: ls pwd cd mkdir rm etc

Comment: Does this answer your question? [View history of commands run in terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/624848/view-history-of-commands-run-in-terminal)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bash history handling with multiple terminals](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80371/bash-history-handling-with-multiple-terminals)

Comment: yes, history does the thing, but how to print time stamp for each operation?

Comment: Please use the search function, and edit your question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/391082/how-to-see-time-stamps-in-bash-history

Comment: Perhaps this can help: https://www.thegeekdiary.com/how-to-log-every-shell-command-in-linux/